# How to know if user choose to show full post or excerpt?

Tags: themes, content

I've seen there is a setting to choose whether to see full posts or excerpts on feed. However I'm using a theme that doesn't seem to support this functionality (it always show the full post). For this reason I created a child theme and would like to know what function to use to check what the user chose from preferences. e.g:

```
<?php if ( did_the_user_choose_excerpts() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
    // Full post
```

How do I check if the user chose to see excerpts?

Comment: How about `if(!empty(get_the_exceprt())) : show excerpt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Show summary or full textx for feeds]

That option refers to show excerpt on [rss/atom feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds), not to normal frontend archives.

You can get that value using

```
get_option( 'rss_use_excerpt' );
```

That is **1** if user choose "Summary", **0** if user choose "Full text".